# Unity How to change unity's 3D Object parameters via C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I’m trying to make an FPS character crouch. I started with a script to shrink the character controller. It works fine, but the cylinder that I’m using as a player doesn't change height. It clips through the floor. How can I create a script to change the cylinder's height? I haven't found documentation about this. Is there any better way to create the crouch script? Should I opt for rigidbody instead of character controller? I'm fairly new to unity and C# so your advice would help a lot.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CapsuleCollider-height.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your script with the character controller, but changing also the **cylinder collider**.

For example, you could:

```
Collider coll;
```

And in the `Start()` function:

```
coll = this.gameObject.GetComponent<CylinderCollider>();
```

Then when you crouch you can easily

```
coll.Height = 5f;
coll.y = 32f;
coll.isTrigger = false;
```

Basically, you can play with the variables you see in the inspector and use what fits better

Comment: I may as well be wrong, but since I'm using character controller for the movement like walking sprinting and jumping doesn’t  capsule collider make one more collide system?? I mean without it, I can bump into objects and the code works just fine

Comment: You can use my code for any collider, just change GetComponent to fit your collider @Bubble07